# PHP update database on close window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onbeforeunload

I am trying to update the database when the user close or refresh the browser. This is my code:

```
$(window).bind('unload', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        async: false,
        url: 'liberaLugar.php?idCurso=2'
    });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you in most cases. of course, if your server is unreachable, you could freeze the browser, so we should also add a timeout. it may also be helpul to give your user some visual indicator of what the hell is going on, so we should set the cursor to waiting.

```
var unloaded = false;
$(window).on('beforeunload', unload);
$(window).on('unload', unload);  
function unload(){      
    if(!unloaded){
        $('body').css('cursor','wait');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            async: false,
            url: 'liberaLugar.php?idCurso=2',
            success:function(){ 
                unloaded = true; 
                $('body').css('cursor','default');
            },
            timeout: 5000
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Synchronous AJAX is now deprecated in Webkit Browsers.**

Comment: This worked perfectly! thank you very much. just one more thing, if I submit the form how can I ignore these events? maybe a global variable?

Comment: @AndresCavazos yes, set a global in your form submit code the way i have in this example. then in the unload function, check the variable for truth, and if true return false.

Comment: @r3wt, if *Synchronous AJAX is now deprecated in Webkit Browsers* how then it's possible to realize in those browsers?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin i don't know if you still can, but perhaps if you add an `if(confirm('some message'){ ... }` block it might allow you to do a normal async request. I would suggest you are just going to have to experiment, if this is something you truly need. an alternative strategy might be having a ping endpoint on your server, and when it doesn't hear from a user for 5 minutes, it does the work that it used to do with the ajax request. hope that helps.