# Check if webpage is closed and run process

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a function that needs to know if the user has closed a page (either by tab, or backing out, or whatever) and run a MVC Controller so I can run a few internal processes. Is this feasible with Javascript or AJAX or impossible? I have the following code:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function (e) {
    // code to execute when browser is closed
    e.$.post("/Functions/Left" });

});
```

But its not doing anything as far as I can see. The Controller processes some database information, and yes it has HTTPPOST.

EDIT: Tried out the following:

var unloaded = false;

```
                        $(window).on('beforeunload', unload);
                        $(window).on('unload', unload);

                        function unload() {

                            if (!unloaded) {


                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'get',
                                    async: false,
                                    url: '/Function/Left/@ViewBag.ID',
                                    success: function () {
                                        unloaded = true;
                                        $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
                                    },
                                    timeout: 5000
                                });
                            }
                        }
```

Its not firing anything though, and I changed the controller to GET.

Comment: `beforeunload` isn't what you want if you just want to trigger when the user is gone, under any situation. JQuery has a nice shortcut called `unload`, documentation at http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: Thanks, will read the docs.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27217583/2401804

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP update database on close window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27217289/php-update-database-on-close-window)

Comment: tried that and its not firing the controller